# Como estilizar a barra de rolagem?

Tags: css, css3, rolamento

Boas,

Tenho perdido algum tempo à procura de soluções para isto mas não encontro, tenho uma *scrollbar* e gostava de diminuir o seu tamanho.
Alguém me pode indicar algum site ou me dizer o que é preciso para fazer com que isto seja possível:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Para navegadores `webkit` (Chrome, Safari, Opera 15+):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* 1 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* 2 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* 3 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* 4 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* 5 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* 6 */ }
::-webkit-resizer                { /* 7 */ }
```

[image]

Créditos do código acima: <kbd>[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)</kbd>

Para criar um scrollbar exactamente como no da imagem da tua pergunta seria algo deste genero:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    background: #F4F4F4;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #dad7d7;
}
```

Eis um exemplo online no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nach90sq/

---

Contudo o código acima não irá funcionar no Internet Explorer, mas para isso podes usar isto:

```
scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB;
scrollbar-arrow-color: black;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
```

[image]

Créditos do código acima: <kbd>[Codemug](http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/)</kbd>

Alternativamente podes sempre **[pesquisar no Google](https://www.google.pt/?#q=jquery+custom+scrollbar)** por jQuery plugins para scrollbars, e irás encontrar plugins como:

- [Perfect Scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar)
- [Nano Scroller](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/)
- [Malihu Custom Scroll Bar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller)

Comment: Obrigado era mesmo isso que andava a procura

Comment: Eu alterei a scroll bar com css, porem as alterações ficam em TODAS paginas do site, gostaria que ficasse apenas na pagina que alterei... alguma ideia? Estou usando vue components, não sei se isto afeta