# Existe alguma forma de uma div assumir o papel do scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, rolamento

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
$("#scroll").draggable({ axis: "x", scroll: true, containment: "#area" });
```

```css
.area{
 position: absolute;
 width: 1010px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-left:10px;
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 
 border: 1px rgb(89,89,89) solid;
 
}

.scroll{
 position: absolute;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-left:10px;
 
 width: 35px;
 height: 110px;
 
 border: 4px rgb(161, 233, 240) solid;
 
 background-position: bottom center;
 background-size: 35px 30px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border-radius: 20px;
 
 -moz-box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0),inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
 -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0),inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
 box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0),inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="area" class="area">testeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
<div id="scroll" class="scroll draggable"></div>
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma da minha `div scroll` assumir o lugar do `scroll` padrão do navegador...

E mais, toda vez que seleciono a `div scroll` pela primeira vez, ela da um "salto" de uns 10 pixels pro lado e não volta pra posição original.... queria corrigir esse problema....

Comment: Se estás à procura de estilizar a barra de `scroll`, acho que devias dar uma olhada [**nesta pergunta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68935/11886) e considerar utilizar uma dessas opções pois o que estas a tentar fazer aqui não aparenta ser lá muito boa idea :P

Comment: Pois e, já dei uma olhada na sua resposta, mas infelizmente, não soluciona o meu problema rs, preciso mesmo utilizar uma `div` como `scroll` :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar o [**`Range Input`**](http://demosthenes.info/blog/757/Playing-With-The-HTML5-range-Slider-Input) como uma scrollbar personalizada

Podes ler mais sobre isto em: [JQuery Tools Rangeinput](http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/rangeinput/scrollbar.html) (fonte do código abaixo)

Exemplo no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qw75wgeg

```js
// get handle to the scrollable DIV
var scroll = $("#scroll");
 
// initialize rangeinput
$(":range").rangeinput({
 
 // slide the DIV along with the range using jQuery's css() method
 onSlide: function(ev, step)  {
  scroll.css({left: -step});
 },
 
 // display progressbar
 progress: true,
 
 // initial value. also sets the DIV's initial scroll position
 value: 100,
 
 // this is called when the slider is clicked. we animate the DIV
 change: function(e, i) {
  scroll.animate({left: -i}, "fast");
 },
 
 // disable drag handle animation when when slider is clicked
 speed: 0
 
});
```

```css
/* outermost element for the scroller (stays still) */
#scrollwrap {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px #666;
}

/* the element that moves forward/backward */
#scroll {
    position:relative;
    width:20000em;
    padding:20px 100px;
    font:bold 90px  sans-serif;
    height:150px;
    background-color: #4679BD;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:5px 1px 1px #000;
    left:-100px;
}

.slider {
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:1px;
    border:2px solid #00118E;
    width:98%;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
}

.progress {
    background-color:#00118E;
    height:3px;
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
}

.handle {
    border: 4px rgb(161, 233, 240) solid;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0),inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color:#fff;
    height:20px;
    width:80px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-12px;
    display:block;
    cursor:move;
    -moz-border-radius:14px;
    -webkit-border-radius:14px;
}

.handle:active {
    background-color: #4679BD;
}

.range {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<!-- our scrollable element -->
<div id="scrollwrap">
  <div id="scroll">
    jQuery TOOLS 1.2.6  Rangeinput. HTML5 ranges for humans.
  </div>
</div>
 
<!-- rangeinput that controls the scroll -->
<input type="range" max="2600" step="10" />
```